# Ocassional error number 0 executing query in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am developing an application with code igniter and sometimes I got this error when I am calling a view that is loading data from the dabase:

```
Error Number: 0

SELECT `medidas_ludlum_5min`.* FROM (`medidas_ludlum_5min`) WHERE (FK_ludlum="190.26.88.131" and measurement >= "0.0" and fecha between "2014/04/01 11:49:03" and "2014/05/27 11:49:03")

Filename: C:\xampp-win32-1.7.5-VC9\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Can some one help me to figure it out what is related to error 0? Or what can be happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look at the [simple_query](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html) function. It seems that the usual query function has a mysql diver bug: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/181751/#860516
If it returns false there might be something else wrong with the query.
Maybe an uneacaped value

Comment: no mate, because as I said it is happening sometimes, not all the times, so if I had an error in the sintaxys the error should be happen always

Comment: I dont know if this works for me, because the issue is being generated when I use the grocerycrud library for example here:  $crud->where('(FK_ludlum="'.$ludlum_id.'"
                and  measurement >= "'.$medida.'"               
                and fecha between "'.$fechainicio.'" and "'.$fechafin.'")',null,FALSE);